# Cocos2d - jerky scroll movement (follow a CCNode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

i have a question about a smooth scroll implementation. In my game i have a horizontal scroll. The current implementation look like this:

```
//Update method
float offset = _hero.position.x;
float offsetY = _hero.position.y;
float scaleToCalculateWith = _follower.scale;

float posX = (_winSize.width/4-offset*scaleToCalculateWith);
float posY = (_winSize.height/2-offsetY*scaleToCalculateWith);

//16px is the general value between the follower and the 
//hero position at a velocity of 30
if(_lastX - _follower.position.x > 16){
    NSLog(@"%f", _lastX - _follower.position.x);
}
_lastX = _follower.position.x;

//_follower is just a CCNode
_follower.position = ccp(posX, posY);
```

I use Box2D for the physics. In create a simulation to reproduce the jitter. In the simulation i have a world without any gravity and a circle shape which has a velocity of `b2Vec2(0, 30)`.

As you can see i log the difference between the last and current position of the follower node. The log look like this:

```
2015-03-14 13:00:23.921 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 53.312500
2015-03-14 13:00:26.554 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 21.250000
2015-03-14 13:01:00.142 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 64.000000
2015-03-14 13:01:04.360 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 22.406250
2015-03-14 13:01:04.613 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 42.750000
2015-03-14 13:01:06.321 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 21.343750
2015-03-14 13:01:08.087 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 21.406250
2015-03-14 13:01:09.626 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 21.343750
2015-03-14 13:01:16.722 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 21.343750
2015-03-14 13:01:17.654 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 21.250000
2015-03-14 13:01:21.808 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 21.250000
2015-03-14 13:01:25.090 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 53.000000
2015-03-14 13:01:45.654 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 42.625000
2015-03-14 13:02:00.126 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 31.968750
2015-03-14 13:02:00.144 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 53.312500
2015-03-14 13:02:06.204 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 42.656250
2015-03-14 13:02:09.654 jitterysimulation[1567:60b] 21.343750
```

There is sometimes this jumping of the follower. The simulation runs stable with a constant FPS of 60 and a CPU usage under 30% on a iphone 4 (device). The Box2d update is in the same update method like the follower position update.

How can i prevent these stutter? Is this a general problem of games?

I would upload the simulation on dropbox if someone is interested in.

Thank you in advance.